# How to incorporate same functionalities of GVRViewerMain and GVRFPScanvas while using the current versions of GVR sdk

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-vr, google-vr-sdk

In the recent versions of GoogleVR sdk for unity, I have noticed there is no **GVRviewermain** (to split the view for left and right eye) and also no **GVRFPScanvas** (to record the FPS). Can anyone please tell me how to achieve the functionalities of these two modules using the current GVR components?

Answer (score 0):

You can't split the view for the left and the right eye in recent versions of GoogleVR sdk. But about the FPS you can make World Space Canvas as a child of Camera and put text field in it, set the text field in camera view and attach following scipt to Canvas.

```
float deltaTime = 0.0f;

public Text textField;

void Update()
{
    float msec = deltaTime * 1000.0f;
    float fps = 1.0f / deltaTime;
    string text = string.Format("{0:0,0} ms ({1:0.} fps)", msec, fps);
    deltaTime += (Time.deltaTime - deltaTime) * 0.1f;

    tekst.text = text;
}
```